# Python ~ accessing tuple members in template class

Tags: python, sqlite, dictionary

I am new to Python - be forewarned!

I have a template class that takes a list as an argument and applies the members of the list to the template. Here's the first class:

```
class ListTemplate:

    def __init__(self, input_list=[]):
        self.input_list = input_list

    def __str__(self):
        return "\n".join([self._template % x for x in self.input_list])
```

Here's the template code/class:

```
class HTML_Template(ListTemplate):

    _template = """ 
      <li>
        <table width="100%%" border="0">
          <tr>
            <td>Title: %(title)s</td>
            <td>Link: %(isbn)s</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Author: %(author)s</td>
            <td>Date: %(pub_date)s</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Summary: %(isbn)s</td>
            <td>Description: %(descr)s</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <hr>
      </li>"""
```

Here's the problem:

I'm pulling data from a sqlite database using fetchall, which return a list of tuples. I can pass this list of tuples to this method fine by changing the template to %s instead of %(isbn) ...etc., however, I need to access the isbn member multiple times in the template. To do this now, I load the tuples in to dictionaries and push them into another list ...then pass the list of dictionaries. This strikes me as inefficient. My question is: how would you rewrite this so that the original list of tuples could be passed to the template (thus, saving a step ), while still allowing access to the individual members by ie., item[0] or similar?

Thanks ~

Bubnoff

Comment: As an aside, using a list as default argument (like in `def __init__(self, input_list=[]):`) is not usually a good step. See [here](http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the [new string formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format), it may be possible to operate solely on indices...

But that will be horrible to decipher, even with the database scheme at hand. The list-of-dict approach sounds much saner, and unless you operate a really frequently-visited service, the performance impact won't be too bad (this depends on the size of the data set - but you don't get 3k 7-tuples at once, do you?). Dictionaries are rather efficient in Python. Caching could also help performance-wise.

Comment: Thank you! That works for me. I'll look into caching, though I don't really need it in this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python 2.6 or newer, you can use the [`format`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method of strings instead of the `%` operator. This allows you to specify the index of the given arguments:

```
>>> template = 'First value: {0}, Second value: {1}, First again: {0}'
>>> values = (123, 456)
>>> template.format(*values)
'First value: 123, Second value: 456, First again: 123'
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this in 2.5.2 using import future ...etc.?

Comment: @Bubnoff: I don't know of a built-in way to do this in 2.5.